How do I use dcmtk to create images in DICOM format?
I want to create multiple frames of images in DICOM format, and the format of the images can be viewed using dcmdump as follows:



Tag
Value




(7fe0,0010)
OB (PixelSequence #=2)


(fffe,e000)
pi (no value available)


(fffe,e000)
pi ff\d8\ff\e0\00\10\4a\46\49\46\00\01\01\00\00\01\00\01\00\00\ff\c3... (244388 bytes)


(fffe,e0dd)
(SequenceDelimitationItem)



It is to write an item into the tag of (7fe0,0010).
cv::Mat image2(10, 10, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(255));
cv::imshow("image2", image2);
cv::waitKey(0);

DcmFileFormat fileformat;
DcmDataset *dataset = fileformat.getDataset();
dataset->putAndInsertString(DCM_PatientName, "TestName");
dataset->putAndInsertString(DCM_PatientSex, "M");
dataset->putAndInsertUint16(DCM_Rows, image2.rows);
dataset->putAndInsertUint16(DCM_Columns, image2.cols);
dataset->putAndInsertString(DCM_PhotometricInterpretation, "MONOCHROME2");
dataset->putAndInsertUint16(DCM_BitsAllocated, 8);
dataset->putAndInsertUint16(DCM_BitsStored, 8);
dataset->putAndInsertUint16(DCM_HighBit, 7);
dataset->putAndInsertUint16(DCM_PixelRepresentation, 0); // unsigned
unsigned long rows = image2.rows;
unsigned long cols = image2.cols;
Uint8 *pixels = new Uint8[rows * cols];
for (unsigned long i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for (unsigned long j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        pixels[i * cols + j] = image2.at<uchar>(i, j);

DcmPixelSequence *pixelSeq = new DcmPixelSequence(DCM_PixelData);

//DcmItem *item = new DcmItem();
//item->putAndInsertUint8Array(DcmTag(DCM_Item, EVR_pixelItem),pixels,(rows*cols));
//pixelSequence->insert(item);

dataset->insert(pixelSeq);


OFCondition writeStatus = fileformat.saveFile("multiframe.dcm", EXS_LittleEndianExplicit);
if (writeStatus.bad())
{
    cout << "Failed to write the DICOM file!" << endl;
    return 1;
}

In the above code, the generated DCM format is viewed using dcmdump：



tag
value




(7fe0,0010)
OB (PixelSequence #=0)


(fffe,e0dd)
(SequenceDelimitationItem)



But how do I unravel the group annotation section? If I use dcmdump to view the saved dcm format, there will be errors：
"Item (fffe,e000) larger (4294967295) than remaining bytes in file"
How do I save the pixel data sequence I want correctly?

You only have a single item in your pixel sequence, it seems. From a bit of searching it seems that the first thing after the sequence contains the offsets of individual frames in the second thing. What happens if you call ->insert multiple times?

If you really want to save images in Explicit VR Little Endian into a DICOM file, then you should not need to use encapsulated pixel data at all. That arrangement in Pixel Data seen from the output of dcmdump only applies to files which were encoded as such, but if saving the images uncompressed is fine and intended, then the pixel data sequence should not be necessary, even when encoding multiple frames.
Using native pixel data
Assuming that the pixel data samples are already arranged in the right order, insert the bytes into the data set directly. When working with multiple frames, concatenate them all into one array.
dataset->putAndInsertUint8Array(DCM_PixelData, pixels, (rows * cols));

Using encapsulated pixel data
Should the use of encapsulated pixel data be strictly necessary, you can either compress the pixel data into a supported image encoding and set the transfer syntax accordingly, or proceed with using the uncompressed bytes with the transfer syntax Encapsulated Uncompressed Explicit VR Little Endian. The latter case might not work as of dcmtk 3.6.8, but it might be possible in the future (issue 1000). This transfer syntax is relatively new, so you may want to validate that your other devices and tools support this.
According to the DICOM standard and the Dcmtk documentation itself, the first item of a pixel data sequence must be the basic offset table, but it can be left empty. So, first you need to insert an empty item (or inspect the standard and build the offset table based on the frames to write), followed by the encoded pixel data fragments.
DcmPixelSequence *pixelSeq = new DcmPixelSequence(DCM_PixelData);

// empty offset table
DcmPixelItem *offsetTable = new DcmPixelItem(DCM_PixelItemTag);
pixelSeq->insert(offsetTable);

// my frame (encode it first)
DcmPixelItem *item = new DcmPixelItem();
item->putAndInsertUint8Array(DcmTag(DCM_Item, EVR_pixelItem), encoded_pixels, encoded_pixels.size());
pixelSeq->insert(item);

dataset->insert(pixelSeq);

// ! use the right transfer syntax here !
auto ts = EXS_JPEGProcess14SV1;
OFCondition writeStatus = fileformat.saveFile("multiframe.dcm", ts);

See also:

How to encapsulate the H.264 bitstream of video file in C++

